# How to get coordinates of a place on DoubleTap in android?

Tags: android, events, double, tap

Hi i want to get coordinates from the map on double tap event. Currently my app is returning coordinates and name of the place on single tap, which makes it very busy and slow.
Kindly help me out and if possible show me some code sample.